# Get project name of WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reflection

I'm writing my first WPF application, and I'm trying to get the name of the project so I can output it.  However, using

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName()
```

or

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()
```

gets me the name as well as the version number(i.e., DataPusher, Version=2.0.466.16967).

Is there a way to get ONLY the assembly name?  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

or

```
string name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Alternatively, you can get the `Assembly` object from any known type in the assembly:

```
Assembly assy = typeof({class name here}).Assembly;
```

This also allows another option to get the the name only:

```
string name = typeof({class name here}).Assembly.GetName().Name;
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Since you were the first one with the working answer, you'll get the check as soon as it lets me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Application.ResourceAssembly.FullName will prevent you from having to import System.Reflection also.