# XAML How to get a project name

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, text, resources

Im learning XAML with microsoft visual studio 2013 wpf application.

I want to make a textblock display my Project Name from a some kind of resource(?) - I want to make a template :) .

Thank you for help in advance :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

or

```
string name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
Alternatively, you can get the Assembly object from any known type in the assembly:
Assembly assy = typeof({class name here}).Assembly;
```

This also allows another option to get the the name only:

```
string name = typeof({class name here}).Assembly.GetName().Name;
```

[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862416/get-project-name-of-wpf-project?s=9%7C0.6759)